# subprocess.check_output quicker way

Tags: python, subprocess

```
 prules=subprocess.check_output("perl ruleFinder.pl "+datasetfile+" "+myrulepath, shell=True)##call a different program to produce a list of rules that predict contact
```

I am using this code to call another program and get the data produced from this program. Using this is takes about a minute to finish. Is there a quicker more efficient function I could use?

Comment: How long does it take to run the same command from the shell (or command prompt)? Are you sure if subprocess.check_output() is the bottle neck?

Comment: Is using `shell=True` really necessary? It brings a lot of trouble, especially if you have whitespace in your file name. Did you try `subprocess.check_output(['perl', 'ruleFinder.pl', datasetfile, myrulepath])`

Comment: I agree regarding `shell=True`. Passing a list of arguments is much cleaner.

Comment: whats wrong with `shell=True`? I'll try that now thanks

Comment: Whilst you should use the `subprocess` command suggested by @glglgl, it won't make any difference to your execution time.

Comment: @miik As I said: What happens if `datasetfile='My neat file'` or `myrulepath='/home/myusername/My Data Files/'` or even contain tab or newline characters? These are perfectly valid file names. No reason to reject them or rule them out voluntarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subprocess.check_output` simply starts the other process and waits for it to complete. That's taking a minute to happen, but the time is not spent executing `subprocess.check_output`. The time is spent executing the other process. The only way to speed things up is to speed up that other process.